# wpf material design demo

Tags: wpf, dynamic

i am new to visual studio wpf. so i try to make application using material design demo app.
[material design in xaml toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX5KG.png)
i install the material design themes library package and copy paste some source code in material design web in app.xaml and mainWindow.xaml. and i try to copy and paste a code from WPF demo app(material design in xaml toolkit).then some errors are arisen. following code used to get "field" using following code.

```css
<TextBox
  x:Name="NameTextBox"
  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name"
  materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperText="Helper text longer than error">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding
      Path="Name"
      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <domain:NotEmptyValidationRule
          ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignDemo.Domain" />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQIde.png

following error appears.

Error   XDG0008 The name "NotEmptyValidationRule" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MaterialDesignDemo.Domain".

Error   XLS0414 The type 'domain:NotEmptyValidationRule' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgHae.png)

some other component also can not add .

how resolve this?

Comment: Did you *verify that you are not missing an assembly reference*, as the error message says?

Comment: Where did you copy the code from?

Comment: i copied code from material design in xaml Toolkit. this app show us demo and relevant source code. (https://imgur.com/luWHXCf)

Answer (score 0):

I added
..//NotEmptyValidationRule.cs
to my project, and the error message disappeared.

Anyway the Commobbox still can't work.
Hope to help you.

Thanks.